# How to get id from selectpicker after add textboxs dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```js
$("#oriother").on('change', function() {

  if ($(this).val() === 'Other Business') {
    $("#orihdother").removeClass('notvisible');
  }

  $("#orilocation").prop('disabled', false);
  $("#orilocation").selectpicker('refresh');
});


function addline() {
  var line = $('<div class="col-md-6"><div class="form-group"><label ><?= $vendorqualotherbusiness ?></label><select class="form-control txtvendorqualotherbusiness" id="copyother<%=count++%>" style="cursor:pointer;"><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>Other Business</option></select></div></div><div class="col-md-6"><div class="col-md-11" style="padding-left: 0 !important;"><div class="form-group"><label ><?= $vendorquallocation ?></label><select class="form-control selectpicker txtvendorquallocation" multiple data-live-search="true" id="copylocation<%=count++%>" style="cursor:pointer;" disabled required><option>Auto Complete</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option></select></div></div><div class="col-md-1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" onclick="addline();" style="position: relative;top: 30px;right: 15px;font-size: 25px; cursor: pointer;"></i></div></div><div class="col-md-6" style="margin-right: 1px;"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control hdvendorqualotherbusiness notvisible" id="copyhdother<%=count++%>" required></div></div>');

  $('.newline').append(line);

  $('select[id^="copyother"]').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() === 'Other Business') {
      $('input[id^="copyhdother"]').removeClass('notvisible');
    }

    $('select[id^="copylocation"]').prop('disabled', false);
    $('select[id^="copylocation"]').selectpicker('refresh');
  });
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Vendor Qualification</label>
      <select class="form-control txtvendorqualotherbusiness" id="oriother" style="cursor:pointer;">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>Other Business</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="col-md-11" style="padding-left: 0 !important;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Location</label>
        <select class="form-control selectpicker txtvendorquallocation" multiple data-live-search="true" id="orilocation" style="cursor:pointer;" disabled required>
          <option>Auto Complete</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
          <option>4</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" onclick="addline();" style="position: relative;top: 30px;right: 15px;font-size: 25px; cursor: pointer;"></i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-right: 1px;">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control hdvendorqualotherbusiness notvisible" id="orihdother" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="newline"></div>

</div>
```

**This is my html code**

well, my purpose is when i try to choose an option from a regular select option the following selectpicker will be enabled, and when i try to choose an *'Other Business'* from regular select option, the input text will be show

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label >Vendor Qualification</label>
            <select class="form-control txtvendorqualotherbusiness" id="oriother" style="cursor:pointer;">
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>Other Business</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-11" style="padding-left: 0 !important;">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label >Location</label>
                <select class="form-control selectpicker txtvendorquallocation" multiple data-live-search="true" id="orilocation" style="cursor:pointer;" disabled required>
                    <option>Auto Complete</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" onclick="addline();" style="position: relative;top: 30px;right: 15px;font-size: 25px; cursor: pointer;"></i>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-right: 1px;">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control hdvendorqualotherbusiness notvisible" id="orihdother" required>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="newline"></div>

</div>
```

**This is my javascript code**

my problem is, when i try to append it works properly, but the selectpicker not show anything, and when i try to choose *'Other Business'*, the input text will show for every single line

```
$("#oriother").on('change', function(){

        if($(this).val() === 'Other Business'){
            $("#orihdother").removeClass('notvisible');
        }

        $("#orilocation").prop('disabled', false);
        $("#orilocation").selectpicker('refresh');
    });


function addline(){ 
    var line = $('<div class="col-md-6"><div class="form-group"><label ><?= $vendorqualotherbusiness ?></label><select class="form-control txtvendorqualotherbusiness" id="copyother<%=count++%>" style="cursor:pointer;"><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>Other Business</option></select></div></div><div class="col-md-6"><div class="col-md-11" style="padding-left: 0 !important;"><div class="form-group"><label ><?= $vendorquallocation ?></label><select class="form-control selectpicker txtvendorquallocation" multiple data-live-search="true" id="copylocation<%=count++%>" style="cursor:pointer;" disabled required><option>Auto Complete</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option></select></div></div><div class="col-md-1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" onclick="addline();" style="position: relative;top: 30px;right: 15px;font-size: 25px; cursor: pointer;"></i></div></div><div class="col-md-6" style="margin-right: 1px;"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control hdvendorqualotherbusiness notvisible" id="copyhdother<%=count++%>" required></div></div>');

    $('.newline').append(line);

    $('select[id^="copyother"]').on('change', function(){
        if($(this).val() === 'Other Business'){
            $('input[id^="copyhdother"]').removeClass('notvisible');
        }

        $('select[id^="copylocation"]').prop('disabled', false);
        $('select[id^="copylocation"]').selectpicker('refresh');
    });
}
```

Comment: please edit the question, and replace the code into snipet so we are can help you

Comment: thanks for your suggest, i already edit my question..

Answer (score 0):

```js
let num = Math.ceil( Math.random() * 100); // random number between 1 and 100

$('body').append('<select id="copyother-' + num + '"><option>1</option><option>2</options>');

$('select[id^="copyother"]').on('change', function() {
  let id = $(this).prop('id');
  console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Once you have added your elements dynamically and selecting them using jQuery, you can get the id using `.prop( 'id' );` as in:

```
$( 'select[id^="copyother"]' ).on( 'change', function(){
    let id = $(this).prop( 'id );
    console.log( id );
});
```

Comment: Yes, it does. I have added a snippet with this code showing that even with nothing in the body to begin with, you can dynamically add an element, select it with jQuery, and get the id. You have irrelevant code with inline php in your question but if you boil it down to a runnable example demonstrating the issue you will be able to get help.

Comment: JasonB
what i need in my code is, there are two different select option
the first one is regular select option, the second one is using selectpicker

when i try to add using append, all my lines including the selectpicker works properly added, but the selectpicker didn't show anything

sorry for bad english..

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code

```
function addline(){ 
    var line = $('<div class="col-md-6"><div class="form-group"><label ><?= $vendorqualotherbusiness ?></label><select class="form-control txtvendorqualotherbusiness" id="copyother<%=count++%>" style="cursor:pointer;"><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>Other Business</option></select></div></div><div class="col-md-6"><div class="col-md-11" style="padding-left: 0 !important;"><div class="form-group"><label ><?= $vendorquallocation ?></label><select class="form-control selectpicker txtvendorquallocation" multiple data-live-search="true" id="copylocation<%=count++%>" style="cursor:pointer;" disabled required><option>Auto Complete</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option></select></div></div><div class="col-md-1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" onclick="addline();" style="position: relative;top: 30px;right: 15px;font-size: 25px; cursor: pointer;"></i></div></div><div class="col-md-6" style="margin-right: 1px;"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control hdvendorqualotherbusiness notvisible" id="copyhdother<%=count++%>" required></div></div>');

    $('.newline').append(line);

    $(document).on('change', 'select[id^="copyother"]', function(){
        if($(this).val() === 'Other Business'){
            $('input[id^="copyhdother"]').removeClass('notvisible');
        }

        $('select[id^="copyrowlocation"]').prop('disabled', false);
        $('select[id^="copyrowlocation"]').selectpicker('refresh');
    });
}
```

Instead of `$('select[id^="copyother"]').on('change', function(){` just use this `$(document).on('change', 'select[id^="copyother"]', function(){`.
This will work for all dynamically added inputs.